# Funky (don't know how else to describe) Surface Plot

Tags: pgfplots, groupplots

Below is an MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\begin{document}
    \centering

    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}{fig6}
        \begin{groupplot}[
                height=6cm,
                width=6cm,
                group style={group size=2 by 2,
                             group name = fig6_plots,
                             xlabels at=edge bottom,
                             ylabels at=edge left
                                        },
                            xlabel = {\footnotesize $\rho$},
                            ylabel = {\footnotesize $\gamma$},
                                        colorbar horizontal,
                                        colorbar to name=Fig6Colorbar,
                                        colormap/blackwhite,
                                        y tick label style={
                                            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                                            fixed,
                                            fixed zerofill,
                                            precision=2,
                                            /tikz/.cd
                                        },
                                        x tick label style={
                                            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                                            fixed,
                                            fixed zerofill,
                                            precision=0,
                                            /tikz/.cd
                                        }]
                            \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Increasing $\alpha$}, z buffer=sort]
                                            \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,colormap/blackwhite] file {PlusIncreasingSurface.txt};
                                        \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Decreasing $\alpha$}, z buffer=sort]
                                            \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,colormap/blackwhite] file {PlusDecreasingSurface.txt};
                                        \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Delta from Come and Go},view={0}{90}]
                                            \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,point meta min=-10,point meta max=0] file {PlusIncreasingDeltaSurface.txt};
                                        \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Delta from Come and Go},view={0}{90}]
                                            \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,point meta min=-10,point meta max=0] file {PlusDecreasingDeltaSurface.txt};

        \end{groupplot}
        \node (fig6_Legend) at ($(fig6_plots c1r2.center)!0.5!(fig6_plots c2r2.center)-(0,4.5cm)$){\ref{Fig6Colorbar}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{+Resources Reactive with $\alpha$ Starting at Upper Bound}
    \label{ReactiveDecreasing}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

That produces this output

[image]

When run with the data files linked here

[PlusIncreasingSurface.txt](http://pastebin.com/7kA7p4dc)

[PlusIncreasingDeltaSurface.txt](http://pastebin.com/z5qiqShK)

[PlusDecreasingSurface.txt](http://pastebin.com/dN08JJgE)

[PlusDecreasingDeltaSurface.txt](http://pastebin.com/jPhL8zLE)

So far so good...but given the big difference in scale, I decided to ditch the combined colorbar and let each of the bottom charts have its own scale.  So I commented out the parts about the node and the meta points that produced the combined colorbar, leaving me with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\begin{document}
    \centering

    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}{fig6}
        \begin{groupplot}[
                height=6cm,
                width=6cm,
                group style={group size=2 by 2,
                                         group name = fig6_plots,
                             xlabels at=edge bottom,
                             ylabels at=edge left
                                        },
                            xlabel = {\footnotesize $\rho$},
                            ylabel = {\footnotesize $\gamma$},
                                        colorbar horizontal,
                                        %colorbar to name=Fig6Colorbar,
                                        colormap/blackwhite,
                                        y tick label style={
                                            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                                            fixed,
                                            fixed zerofill,
                                            precision=2,
                                            /tikz/.cd
                                        },
                                        x tick label style={
                                            /pgf/number format/.cd,
                                            fixed,
                                            fixed zerofill,
                                            precision=0,
                                            /tikz/.cd
                                        }]
                            \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Increasing $\alpha$}, z buffer=sort]
                                            \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,colormap/blackwhite] file {PlusIncreasingSurface.txt};
                                        \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Decreasing $\alpha$}, z buffer=sort]
                                            \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,colormap/blackwhite] file {PlusDecreasingSurface.txt};
                                        \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Delta from Come and Go},view={0}{90}]
                                            %\addplot3[surf, shader=interp,point meta min=-10,point meta max=0] file {PlusIncreasingDeltaSurface.txt};
                                            \addplot3[surf, shader=interp] file {PlusIncreasingDeltaSurface.txt};
                                        \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Delta from Come and Go},view={0}{90}]
                                            %\addplot3[surf, shader=interp,point meta min=-10,point meta max=0] file {PlusDecreasingDeltaSurface.txt};
                                            \addplot3[surf, shader=interp] file {PlusDecreasingDeltaSurface.txt};
        \end{groupplot}
        %\node (fig6_Legend) at ($(fig6_plots c1r2.center)!0.5!(fig6_plots c2r2.center)-(0,4.5cm)$){\ref{Fig6Colorbar}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{+Resources Reactive with $\alpha$ Starting at Upper Bound}
    \label{ReactiveDecreasing}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When I run this on the same data, I now get this

[image]

What's with the "slice" at the top of the two contour plots?  It looks like there is an unlabeled colorbar running across the top of each plot?

Bonus question -- how do I change the precision on the ticks in the colorbars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "slice" you see at the top of the two contour plots are actually colorbars for the two uppermost plots. These are included as you have added `colorbar horizontal` to the whole group. Each `axis` environment inherits these options, meaning *every* plot in this group will have its own colorbar. To see this clearly you can increase the vertical spacing between the plots.

To avoid this, you have to move the `colorbar horizontal` option to the axes where you indeed want them. If you want the colorbars of the two contour plots to have the same tick format, you can simply create a new style in `pgfplots`, and apply this to those axes. If you write

```
\pgfplotsset{%
  mycolorbar/.style={%
    colorbar horizontal,
    every colorbar/.append style={%
      x tick label style={%
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=2,
        /tikz/.cd}}}
}
```

*before* the `tikzpicture` environment, you can simply add the option `mycolorbar` to the axes where you want colorbars. If you want different format for the two colorbars, you have to define them in each of the `\nextgroupplot[...]` options.

Thus, the following code gives the output below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.12}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{%
  mycolorbar/.style={%
    colorbar horizontal,
    every colorbar/.append style={%
      x tick label style={%
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=2,
        /tikz/.cd}}}
}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}{fig6}
    \begin{groupplot}[
      height=6cm,
      width=6cm,
      group style={%
        group size=2 by 2,
        group name=fig6_plots,
        xlabels at=edge bottom,
        ylabels at=edge left
      },
      xlabel = {\footnotesize $\rho$},
      ylabel = {\footnotesize $\gamma$},
      %colorbar to name=Fig6Colorbar,
      colormap/blackwhite,
      y tick label style={%
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=2,
        /tikz/.cd
      },
      x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        fixed zerofill,
        precision=0,
        /tikz/.cd
      }
    ]
      \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Increasing $\alpha$}, z buffer=sort]
        \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,colormap/blackwhite] file {PlusIncreasingSurface.txt};
      \nextgroupplot[title={\scriptsize Decreasing $\alpha$}, z buffer=sort]
        \addplot3[surf, shader=interp,colormap/blackwhite] file {PlusDecreasingSurface.txt};
      \nextgroupplot[mycolorbar, title={\scriptsize Delta from Come and Go},view={0}{90}]
        \addplot3[surf, shader=interp] file {PlusIncreasingDeltaSurface.txt};
      \nextgroupplot[mycolorbar, title={\scriptsize Delta from Come and Go},view={0}{90}]
        \addplot3[surf, shader=interp] file {PlusDecreasingDeltaSurface.txt};
    \end{groupplot}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{+Resources Reactive with $\alpha$ Starting at Upper Bound}
  \label{ReactiveDecreasing}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]